SQL script file to dataframe in Python
I have a SQL file that already has the script with comments, temp tables, and everything else. The last query in the file produces the table I need. That's the table I want as a dataframe. Is there a way to do this in Python?
Set up:
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text

server = "servername"
database = "databasename"
driver = "driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + server + '/' + database + '?trusted_connection=yes&' + driver)
print(engine)

Attempt 1: Copy and paste SQL script
query = """ 
long SQL 
script copied from 
SQL file 
"""
pd.read_sql(query, engine)

Attempt 2: Read from file
sql_file = r"C:\Users\username\Documents\Sample Script.sql"

with open(sql_file, 'r') as query:
    query_string = query.read()

pd.read_sql_query(query_string, engine)

Expectation:
pd.read_sql(query, engine) or pd.read_sql_query(query_string, engine) will read and execute the entire script, ignoring comments, creating temp tables, and when the last query is executed, the table produced will be returned.
Result:
"This result object does not return rows. "
"It has been closed automatically."
ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
Both attempts run successfully when the query file does not include temp tables or other queries. Only the first query is ran and then ends.

Don't quote me on this, but I don't know if you can have multiple SQL expressions in the same string that's passed to pandas. To verify this, try setting a variable and selecting it in the same string, and pass that to pandas. I'm not sure it would work

Does your SQL script begin with SET NOCOUNT ON; ?

Hi Gord, I added SET NOCOUNT ON; to the script, but I get the same error.

Does your SQL script have any PRINT statements in it? (p.s. remember to reply to comments)

@GordThompson The SQL script does not have any PRINT statements. It does include several DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp_name; CREATE TABLE #temp_name (...); INSERT INTO #temp_name ... ; and then a final query that uses all the temp tables.

You could try stripping out the comments and any other extraneous stuff to see if that makes a difference.

@GordThompson, thank you for your help! I tested each temp table and found that one in particular was causing the error. A subquery was returning some NULL values for a column. That column was then passed onto the parent query. In my SQL IDE that was not an issue, but Python does not like that. However, this was only an issue when the query was inserted into a temp table. As a standalone query in Python, no error is triggered.

After some testing, I found that the issue is not with multiple queries being run or that temp tables are not accepted. The issue is that for a temp table, a subquery could not pass on a NULL value to the parent query.
My insert query was structured like this:
SELECT sub.year AS year
, sub.location AS location
, SUM(ISNULL(sub.person_value, 0)) AS location_value
FROM (
    SELECT t1.year AS year
    , t1.location AS location
    , MIN(t2.value) AS person_value
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.year = t2.year AND t1.location = t2.location
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY t1.year, t1.location, t2.person
) sub
GROUP BY sub.year, sub.location
ORDER BY sub.year, sub.location
;

By moving the the ISNULL() function to the subquery, I was able to fix the issue.
SELECT sub.year AS year
, sub.location AS location
, SUM(sub.person_value) AS location_value
FROM (
    SELECT t1.year AS year
    , t1.location AS location
    , MIN(ISNULL(t2.value, 0)) AS person_value
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.year = t2.year AND t1.location = t2.location
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY t1.year, t1.location, t2.person
) sub
GROUP BY sub.year, sub.location
ORDER BY sub.year, sub.location
;

Also, SET NOCOUNT ON; was in fact needed too.
